# Appium Inspector keeps Loading on Mac os

Tags: xcode, appium, inspector

Desired Capabilities :
"platformName": "ios",
"appium:platformVersion": "15.4",
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 8",
"appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
"appium:app": "/Users/user/Desktop/Test.app"

Host : 0.0.0.0
Port : 4723
Path : /wd/hub

Appium version - 1.22.2
Appium Inspector Version - 2022.5.1
Mac os version - Monterey 12.3.1
Xcode Version - 13.3.1

Note : I have been using Simulator, And once starting the server Simulator is running at the background, But the Inspector screen on the Appium is showing infinite loader

Appium logs :

```
[WebDriverAgent]     "testmanagerdVersion": 28,
[WebDriverAgent]     "name": "iOS",
[WebDriverAgent]     "sdkVersion": "15.4",
[WebDriverAgent]     "version": "15.4"
[WebDriverAgent]   },
[WebDriverAgent]   "ios": {
[WebDriverAgent]     "simulatorVersion": "15.4",
[WebDriverAgent]     "ip": "192.168.1.8"
[WebDriverAgent]   },
[WebDriverAgent]   "ready": true,
[WebDriverAgent]   "build": {
[WebDriverAgent]     "upgradedAt": "1644399105000",
[WebDriverAgent]     "time": "May  5 2022 13:16:52",
[WebDriverAgent]     "productBundleIdentifier": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"
[WebDriverAgent]   }
[WebDriverAgent] }
[WebDriverAgent] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 9864ms
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1651740198289 (14:13:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.gudsho.beta","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[Xcode]     t =     0.50s Open com.gudsho.beta
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.50s     Launch com.gudsho.beta
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     0.58s         Setting up automation session
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:19.918140+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Waiting up to 10s until com.gudsho.beta is in idle state (including animations)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     2.12s         Wait for com.gudsho.beta to idle
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:26.584535+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] The application 'com.gudsho.beta' is not running in foreground after 5.00 seconds
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:26.591406+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     8.80s Find the Application 'com.apple.springboard'
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =     8.83s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 4637
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":" ","sdkVersion":"15.4","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.springboard"}},"sessionId":"10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F"}
[WD Proxy] Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1651740206692 (14:13:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1651740206692 (14:13:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if this is an undesired behavior.
[BaseDriver] Event 'orientationSet' logged at 1651740206693 (14:13:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] The value of 'elementResponseAttributes' setting did not change. Skipping the update for it
[BaseDriver] The value of 'shouldUseCompactResponses' setting did not change. Skipping the update for it
[Appium] New XCUITestDriver session created successfully, session 3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1651740206693 (14:13:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Cached the protocol value 'W3C' for the new session 3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"platformName":"ios","platformVersion":"15.4","deviceName":"iPhone 8","automationName":"XCUITest","app":"/Users/user/Desktop/GudSho.app","includeSafariInWebviews":true,"newCommandTimeout":3600,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true,"udid":"8C8DD270-D945-45D8-B498-875111829BA0"}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 35603 ms - 545
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getScreenshot'
[XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F/screenshot] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 \"Cannot take a screenshot within 20000 ms timeout\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot take a screenshot within 20000 ms timeout}","traceback":""},"sessionId":"10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F"}
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen
[XCUITest] Error getting screenshot: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Cannot take a screenshot within 20000 ms timeout" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot take a screenshot within 20000 ms timeout}
[XCUITest] Falling back to 'simctl io screenshot' API
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getScreenshot() result: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAAU2CAYAAADK1zMGAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAERlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAC7qADAAQAAAABAAAFNgAAAACw0axrAABAAElEQVR4AeydCcBt1dz/173dJqGEiCRTQsrULaGuIqWQKFFShuoNyVCSEC/+GSJNGpXiTYomKqVESa4hMqQomQkZmqd7//uzzlnn7rOffcZ9nv2cc5/Pqueevdde42ft4bvW/q2154QQFmd/OglIQAISkIAEJCABCUhgjAnMHeOyWTQJSEACEpCABCQgAQlIoElA4e6pIAEJSEACEpCABCQggQkgoHCfgEayiBKQgAQkIAEJSEACElC4ew5IQAISkIAEJCABCUhgAggo3CegkSyiBCQgAQlIQAISkIAEFO6eAxKQgAQkIAEJSEACEpgAAgr3CWgkiygBCUhAAhKQgAQkIIF5IpCABCQgAQlIQAISkMCkE5g7d2549KMfHdZYY43wgAc8ICy77LJhmWWWmZFq3XfffeGee+4Jt9xyS/jjH/8Yfve734VFixZVLsucLAU/wFQZY/0JPPzhDw8PfehDw4Mf/ODW3z//+c+Q/v7+97+Hv/71r/UXzBwlIAEJSEACEpBAzQRWXHHF8OxnPzusssoqNefcX3b//ve/w/e+971wxx139BehQyiFewcw4+ZNj3HdddcNCxYsCJtvvnl40IMeFO69994wZ86cMG/evLDccsuFu+++O/otXrw4+v3rX/8KF198cfj2t78dfvaznwV6fzoJSEACEpCABCSwNBFgpB19hGhHGP/iF78IDGDeddddIxnlHoYVZVp++eXDQx7ykKjf6Fgg3i+99NJKZRqpcKeQjASvvvrq8dXA9ddfP9ZicYsttgivfvWrw+c///kIcpiGme44MN1mm23C2972tijGV1hhhYFe+yDWOYn5/cxnPhO+9rWv...
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 200 15861 ms - 42
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/screenshot 200 20361 ms - 310864
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/window/rect
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowRect() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getWindowRect'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F/window/size] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:48.082431+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =    30.29s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 4637
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:48.133316+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"width":375,"height":667},"sessionId":"10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F"}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowRect() result: {"width":375,"height":667,"x":0,"y":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/window/rect 200 468 ms - 48
[HTTP] 
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 454 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/source
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getPageSource'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/source?scope=AppiumAUT' to command name 'getPageSource'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /source?scope=AppiumAUT] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/10653560-5FEA-42E8-AA78-9ED1C632378F/source?scope=AppiumAUT] with no body
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:48.149388+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:48.153917+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] The following attributes were requested to be included into the XML: {(
[Xcode]     FBHeightAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBAccessibleAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBValueAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBVisibleAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBWidthAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBEnabledAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBTypeAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBYAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBLabelAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBIndexAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBXAttribute,
[Xcode]     FBNameAttribute
[Xcode] )}
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:48.154613+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4823:99379] Waiting up to 2s until com.apple.springboard is in idle state (including animations)
[Xcode]     t =    30.36s Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =    30.37s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 4637
[Xcode] 
[WD Proxy] socket hang up
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)]     at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:274:13)
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)]     at runMicrotasks ()
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/source 500 639 ms - 677
[HTTP] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:13:50.026006+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[4866:100431] Running tests...
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Restarting after unexpected exit, crash, or test timeout in -[UITestingUITests testRunner]; summary will include totals from previous launches.
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.491
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' started at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.492
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' started at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.492
[Xcode] 
[Xcode]     t =      nans Suite Set Up
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' failed at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.517.
[Xcode]      Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.025) seconds
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' failed at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.518.
[Xcode]      Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.026) seconds
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2022-05-05 14:13:50.519.
[Xcode]      Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.028) seconds
[Xcode] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:14:04.498 xcodebuild[4812:98942] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 53.722 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:14:04.498 xcodebuild[4812:98942] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
[Xcode] 2022-05-05 14:14:04.498 xcodebuild[4812:98942] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 53.722 sec, +53.722 sec -- end
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
[Xcode]     /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-aghlrsejdreqngftgvcqwnjgrbou/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2022.05.05_14-13-10-+0530.xcresult
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Failing tests:
[Xcode]     WebDriverAgentRunner:
[Xcode]         -[UITestingUITests testRunner]
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Testing started
[Xcode] 
[WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 2 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 3 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 2 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Calling AppiumDriver.getTimeouts() with args: ["3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getTimeouts'
[W3C (3e1d7a8e)] Responding to client with driver.getTimeouts() result: {"command":3600000,"implicit":0}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/3e1d7a8e-ad22-4319-851e-d100e4c0eb6c/timeouts 304 1 ms - -
[HTTP]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Xcode version 13.3.* you need to update to the latest Appium release [1.22.3](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.22.3) and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks you so much, Now its Working with 1.22.3-4

Comment: that's essential: I updated to Xcode to `13.4.1` , compiled my project and suddently appium inspector stopped working being stuck at loading. I had to open a CLI and use `yarn add appium -g` (or `npm install appium -g` if you use npm)to update. At the end I espected `appium -v` to show `1.22.3` but it showed `1.22.2` . Btw everything started magically working.  I hate them.